# Laravel 5 error Class 'App' not found in

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently learning laravel 5 and wanted to implement the repository concept.
as I understand. I should put an ioc.php and the config folder and put my bindings their

Here is my config/ioc.php

```
<?php 
 App::bind('QuestionRepository', 'IQuestionRepository');
 App::bind('AnswerRepository', 'IAnswerRepository');
```

I get an error `Class 'App' not found in`

Comment: try `\App::bind('QuestionRepository', 'IQuestionRepository')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try prefixing App with \ like `\App`

Comment: Nice but i'd love to understand and im too lazy to google it :)

Answer (score 5):

For my case in lumen 5.4, undefined 'App' class issue solved by facade definition:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my .env file contained a value with spaces after checking out a new project.

Running `php artisan optimize` for the first time would throw this error because my Exception handler was trying to use the '\App' global alias for the App facade. Commenting that code showed the real error;

> "Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes."