# How to interact with database from public folder file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file `test.php` in `public/test` folder. Now I want to retrieve data from the database. I have tried with below way and it doesn't work. It is showing an error. How can I interact with the database from this `test.php` file?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Test' not found

```
use App\Test;

define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'testing');

$test = new Test();
$test->addConnection([
    'driver' => DB_TYPE,
    'host' => DB_HOST,
    'port' => DB_PORT,
    'database' => DB_NAME,
    'username' => DB_USER,
    'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
]);
$test->setAsGlobal();
$test->bootEloquent();
$configs = $test->index();
```

**Test.php model:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

class Test extends Model
{
    public static function index() {
        $configs = DB::select('select * from tests');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32880582/2815635

Comment: It's not working in the public directory.

Comment: Because you're trying to import a class into single a file which doesn't loads all those namespaces.

Comment: I would strongly not recommend calling a model from public class, if you want to create a test url to test of your db connections are correct, you can create a factory to create a Model instance, call that factory from a seeder, and run that seeder from route using Route::get('test/{class}',function($class){ Artisan::call("db:seed",array('--class'=>$class)); });

Comment: @Mahmud Are you still having issue?

Comment: @BasheerKharoti Yes, i am still facing this issue.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud have you seen my message in the chat?

Answer (score 0):

The public directory should only be for things you want to serve publicly. Such as `css` files, `js` files and template images.

You must make your model inside your `App` folder. Make your own folder inside your `App` folder (in your case which is `public`, i think) so that's how you will access it

```
use App\public\test
```

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: It's not an answer and did not understand my question. Read the question again please.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it will not work because the `class` is not found in the file you executed. Either you need to explicitly include the `class` or include the `composer` **autoload file** in order to import those classes. Just try adding the following to your `test.php`

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';` this is not find autoload file also.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud It will find if you properly set the `autoload.php` path. Let me know the full path of `test.php` and `vendor` folder directory

Comment: Full path of `test.php` is `/public/test/test.php`.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud then just require this `require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Path is ok. But the connection error is showing: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\testingapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1131 Stack trace: #`

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud just paste your at kopy.io

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218663/discussion-between-basheer-kharoti-and-chonchol-mahmud).